# How can I access a pushpin already added on the map later with the help of some ID? (Bing maps V8)

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

I have a map where I have added many pushpins & have attached an id with each one of them.

Now, there's a listing of these locations on the right hand in  list, I want to highlight a particular pin on click of it's corresponding listing. How do I access these pushpins with the help of id?

I simply want to do something like this: (This is just a random pseudocode, not an actual function)

```
var e=Microsoft.maps.getPushpin(someID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code sample. It should how to create a list based on pushpin data and link it back to the pushpins themselves using an id: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#QueryAPI_Paging

Source Code: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsV8CodeSamples/blob/master/Samples/Spatial%20Data%20Services/QueryAPI_Paging.html